# Javascript Application error in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-ide

I periodically get this error when running test cases in Selenium IDE:

> There was an unexpected error. Msg: TypeError:
>   testCase.debugContext.currentCommand(...) is undefined
>       Url: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js, line: 239, column: 7
>       .commandComplete@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js:239:7
>       TestLoop.prototype.continueTestWhenConditionIsTrue@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-executionloop.js:163:13
>       .continueTestWhenConditionIsTrue@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-runner.js:210:7
>       fnBind/retval@chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js:60:12

It happens when I am running any test suite and switch from one case to another.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks to have been found here

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/8103

To avoid scrolling through, the bit which looks to be the solution:

Please follow the below steps...Now you guys are able to fix the problem..!

1. Type "about:config" in the address bar of Mozilla Firefox.but not "add:config"
2. Change the settings to "default" for extensions.javaformatters@seleniumhq.org.install-event-fired
   and
   extensions.selenium-ide.pluginsData.
3. Close and Now launch the IDE again.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that and let you know!  Thanks for the response...you're the best!